# No errors shown, Screen shows black, JOGL

Tags: java, opengl

I am trying to learn JOGL from the book "Computer Graphics Programming with OpenGL in Java". So I obviously don't have a working knowledge. I have followed the example precisely and spent a lot of time trying to diagnose what I did wrong. I eventually tried to just run the code provided right from the book and that doesn't even work. I have previously been able to get a triangle to display but a 3D cube is still eluding me. Here's the code verbatim from the book:

```
public class Code extends JFrame implements GLEventListener
{   private GLCanvas myCanvas;
    private int rendering_program;
    private int vao[] = new int[1];
    private int vbo[] = new int[2];
    private float cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ;
    private float cubeLocX, cubeLocY, cubeLocZ;
    private GLSLUtils util = new GLSLUtils();

    public Code()
    {   setTitle("Chapter4 - program1a");
        setSize(600, 600);
        myCanvas = new GLCanvas();
        myCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(myCanvas);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {   GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();

        gl.glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glUseProgram(rendering_program);

        int mv_loc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(rendering_program, "mv_matrix");
        int proj_loc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(rendering_program, "proj_matrix");

        float aspect = (float) myCanvas.getWidth() / (float) myCanvas.getHeight();
        Matrix3D pMat = perspective(60.0f, aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

        Matrix3D vMat = new Matrix3D();
        vMat.translate(-cameraX, -cameraY, -cameraZ);

        Matrix3D mMat = new Matrix3D();
        mMat.translate(cubeLocX, cubeLocY, cubeLocZ);

        Matrix3D mvMat = new Matrix3D();
        mvMat.concatenate(vMat);
        mvMat.concatenate(mMat);

        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(mv_loc, 1, false, mvMat.getFloatValues(), 0);
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, false, pMat.getFloatValues(), 0);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {   GL4 gl = (GL4) drawable.getGL();
        rendering_program = createShaderProgram();
        setupVertices();
        cameraX = 0.0f; cameraY = 0.0f; cameraZ = 8.0f;
        cubeLocX = 0.0f; cubeLocY = -2.0f; cubeLocZ = 0.0f;
    }

    private void setupVertices()
    {   GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        float[] vertex_positions =
        {   -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f
        };

        gl.glGenVertexArrays(vao.length, vao, 0);
        gl.glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
        gl.glGenBuffers(vbo.length, vbo, 0);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        FloatBuffer vertBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertex_positions);
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf.limit()*4, vertBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    private Matrix3D perspective(float fovy, float aspect, float n, float f)
    {   float q = 1.0f / ((float) Math.tan(Math.toRadians(0.5f * fovy)));
        float A = q / aspect;
        float B = (n + f) / (n - f);
        float C = (2.0f * n * f) / (n - f);
        Matrix3D r = new Matrix3D();
        r.setElementAt(0,0,A);
        r.setElementAt(1,1,q);
        r.setElementAt(2,2,B);
        r.setElementAt(3,2,-1.0f);
        r.setElementAt(2,3,C);
        r.setElementAt(3,3,0.0f);
        return r;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { new Code(); }
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {}
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}

    private int createShaderProgram()
    {   GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();

        String vshaderSource[] = readShaderSource("resources/vert.shader");
        String fshaderSource[] = readShaderSource("resources/frag.shader");

        int vShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        int fShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        gl.glShaderSource(vShader, vshaderSource.length, vshaderSource, null, 0);
        gl.glShaderSource(fShader, fshaderSource.length, fshaderSource, null, 0);

        gl.glCompileShader(vShader);
        gl.glCompileShader(fShader);

        int vfprogram = gl.glCreateProgram();
        gl.glAttachShader(vfprogram, vShader);
        gl.glAttachShader(vfprogram, fShader);
        gl.glLinkProgram(vfprogram);
        return vfprogram;
    }

        public String[] readShaderSource(String path) {
            //reads in shader programs
            ArrayList<String> builder = new ArrayList();

            try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.add(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load a shader file!"
                        + System.lineSeparator() + ex.getMessage());
            }


            return builder.toArray(new String[1]);
    }
}
```

Not verbatim I added my own file loader.

the shaders:

```
   #version 430

out vec4 color;

uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

void main(void)
{   color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

---

```
#version 430

layout (location=0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added:

```
GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getMaxProgrammableCore(true);
GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
myCanvas = new GLCanvas(caps);
```

to the books code and it worked.